# Storing polymorphic game objects efficiently in a C++ container

Tags: c++, object, inheritance

For a 2D game I'm working on I have made a vector of pointers to an object. This object is the parent class where all other game objects inherit from. So the actor is such an object, items are, enemies are, etc. The class containing this vector (an object manager) executes virtual functions of this class, such as run() and draw().

For me this was just a straightforward implementation where I did not really think about at the time. Now I've come to a point where I actually have to delete objects from the container. Some quick searches on the internet tell me that a vector implementation is right for this task (using swap and pop), but also that I should store the objects themselves on the vector for even more performance. So: not pointers but the actual instances. This way they are allocated on the stack I guess. Is this even possible when using inheritance? And is there an even faster way to store inherited game objects?

Comment: If you try to store polymorphic objects by-value, then you encounter the *slicing problem*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this even possible when using inheritance?

No, it's not possible to store polymorphic objects in a container without using a pointer or a reference.

The way I would do it is with a combination of [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

```
template<class T> using container = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>;
container<base> vector;
```

The pushing is made via:

```
vector.emplace_back(std::unique_ptr<base>(new item()));
vector.emplace_back(std::unique_ptr<base>(new enemy()));
```

where `base` is the base class and `item` and `enemy` are derived classes.

Comment: `vector.emplace_back( new item() )` would have been enough, I believe.

Comment: @Kalrish IIRC `emplace_back` could potentially throw, leading to memory leak in that case.

Comment: @Jeffrey I hadn't thought about that. Thanks :). Taking that into account, C++14 helps a bit: `vector.emplace_back( std::make_unique<base>(item()) )`. I'm not sure about the syntax, though. Should it be `make_unique<item>()` instead? Also note that `std::make_unique` could be more efficient.

Comment: @Kalrish `std::make_unique` is really just a `std::unique_ptr<T>(new T())` in disguise, nothing terribly more efficient about it. Also in this case I'm afraid you are stuck with `std::unique_ptr<base>(new item())` anyway, because of the `base` pointer; I might be mistaken though, since I don't remember `std::make_unique` either.